# “USB HDD” option replaced by “ubuntu” in BIOS, now cannot use USB boot media

Tags: ubuntu, boot, usb, bios

So, being foolish old me, I tried to use os-uninstaller to remove my Windows installation and make way for Arch Linux.

Unfortunately, now nothing on this computer boots, and I cannot even boot from a USB! The "USB HDD" option has completely disappeared from the BIOS and has been replaced by "ubuntu".

I can't seem to boot from anything, and was looking for a way to restore the ability to boot from USB again.

If it helps, the computer is a Samsung NP540U3C and the BIOS is Phoenix Securecore Tiano Setup.

Also, why would ubuntu remove the ability to boot from USB in the first place? Very perplexed over here.

Comment: Update- there was a recovery utility that has let me boot into a Windows factory image, but I still can't restore the ability to boot from USB.

Answer (score 0):

Try booting from a black usb2.0 port as the blue 3.0 port sometimes does not boot with your particular model; [click here for more info.](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=145874)

Answer (score 0):

Kasi! I don't think Ubuntu did it. Maybe something related to your Ultrabook? model (NP540U3C). I googled this model and found many similar problems (and some even include corrupt Bioses).

It seems that this model is a ultrabook, I have some suggestions:
1- If you have an external CD driver, try to boot from a LIve CD and install ubuntu (or another OS) from there.

2- You can also try to use a friend's Windows-PC to create a bootable usb stik like here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Probably you'll need to get into BIOS menus and explore it's configurations... For example see if you can change the boot order of devices(USB should be the first if you want to boot from it).
And also try to discover what special keys you can use (Del, f11, f12...) there must be one that shows the boot devices menu, so that you'll be able to choose what device to boot from.  Good Luck!